# Wheeled luggage ban in Dubrovnik; when does it start?

Tags: luggage, regulations, croatia

I have to fly to Dubrovnik, Croatia late this summer, but I haven't booked my Olympic Air tickets yet.

I understand that wheeled luggage are going to be banned in the centre of the town, but I am worried about when this ban will start. Some sites say [later this year](https://www.irelandtraveldeals.com/dubrovnik-authorities-ban-wheeled-suitcases-in-old-town/#:%7E:text=In%20a%20bid%20to%20address,be%20implemented%20later%20this%20year.), while others claim that it starts [this summer](https://traveltomorrow.com/dubrovnik-bans-wheeled-suitcases-to-fight-noise-pollution/).

Is someone aware about the official start date of the ban?

Comment: Good to know they don’t want my wife and I visiting there. Carrying my luggage isn’t high on my wish list these days.

Comment: @JonCuster "As of November, designated luggage storage areas will be set up for tourists to leave their suitcases at. The city will then arrange for transportation to the visitors’ accommodation, free of charge"

Comment: Drops at the airport and train station would be quite nice.

Comment: @DJClayworth seems so convoluted that I suspect it will never be done in practice.

Comment: As a Greek I understand the Croatians. Hypertourism can become a problem for the citizens. In Athens Riviera the mayors had called for strict regulations for the seaside night life. Ot could be just a public stunt though. It's interesting to see how the Croatians will handle it - if they actually do something. As the Ancient Greek phrase says, everything should be in balance; just the right amount of tourists for fueling the economy, while not disturbing the locals.

Comment: why are you worried?

Comment: Follow-up: [Which cities have a ban on wheeled luggage?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/181987/1810)

Comment: Because my luggage has wheels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not this year, as [per this interview](https://When%20asked%20if%20there%20will%20be%20a%20fine%20if%20someone%20drags%20a%20suitcase%20along%20Stradun,%20he%20answers:) with the mayor of Dubrovnik in Croatian media:

> When asked if there will be a fine if someone drags a suitcase along Stradun, he answers: "No one will be fined, the goal is to educate. Through the animated film, we wanted to send a message to visitors about what they can expect when they come to Dubrovnik, not with the aim of punishing them, but to we educate."
> ...
> Such a service will be unique, not only in Croatia, but also in the world. **He expects that everything could come to life in a year and a half.** For those who were worried that they would be fined if they dragged their suitcases along Stradun, he said: "We will not punish guests who drag their suitcases behind them at 5 o'clock in the morning because they are going on a plane, even if it hurts our fellow citizens. We will educate them not to do that or to they work as little as possible so that the tenants of the historic core have peace in the morning".

As far as I can tell, no actual regulation has been signed yet and this entire "ban" might just end up being a publicity stunt. In any case, nothing to worry about for this summer.

Comment: I'd read that the fine is 265€, wonder if the mayor changed his mind after the reactions. Thanks for the answer!