# Which cities have a ban on wheeled luggage?

Tags: luggage, regulations

Reading [Wheeled luggage ban in Dubrovnik; when does it start?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/181964/1810) made me wonder: which cities (aside from possibly Dubrovnik, Croatia in the future) have a ban on wheeled luggage?

Comment: Venice, Italy it seems, but I'm not sure it's enforced

Comment: @Berend this [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g187870-i57-k10869410-Ban_on_rolling_suitcases-Venice_Veneto.html) post says *"The original proposal was about banning the big, noisy carts used to carry goods up and down the bridges in the early moring. Unfortunately the story wasn't properly translated into English. The Venice councillor who signed the draft is still wondering how wheeled carts became tourists' luggage on the international press"* ...

Comment: ... and this [Independent](https://www.independent.co.uk/travel/europe/venice-bans-wheel-suitcases-to-stop-noise-pollution-and-protect-its-historic-streets-9880369.html) story said that pneumatic wheels will be allowed - as if luggage has them!

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, and many press stories copying each other. I couldn't find anything about it on the official Venice tourist site either

Comment: @Berend maybe it was just an ill-advised attempt that originally included both hard-wheeled carts and luggage: even the reputable [Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/italy/11243670/Venice-seeks-to-ban-noisy-suitcases-on-wheels.html) reported it.

Comment: Venice never had one @Berend https://www.eurocheapo.com/blog/roll-folks-venice-not-going-ban-rolling-suitcase.html. The ban only is regarding carts and pallets ([OG statement in Italian from the acting mayor](https://web.archive.org/web/20141225151423/http://www.comune.venezia.it/flex/cm/pages/ServeBLOB.php/L/IT/IDPagina/78727))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Outside of Dubrovnik later, none as far as I can search

- Venice had a [mass press coverage](https://www.cnn.com/travel/article/italy-venice-wheeled-suitcases/index.html) of one that was [mistakingly](https://www.eurocheapo.com/blog/roll-folks-venice-not-going-ban-rolling-suitcase.html) regarded as a ban on suitcases, but it is a ban on carts and pallets [Archived statement by the then acting mayor](https://web.archive.org/web/20141225151423/http://www.comune.venezia.it/flex/cm/pages/ServeBLOB.php/L/IT/IDPagina/78727)

Comment: In Venice proper you do not want luggage you need to roll, too many bridges with steps.